# VBA - divide value in column

Tags: vba, divide

as I am a complete newb in VBA, I have a question.

I have a column of integers, which I want to divide by 60. The column is "X". Here's my code:

```
For Each element In Worksheets("parsed").Range("X1:X" & MaxRows).Cells
    element.Value = element.Value / 60
Next
```

But I always get "type mismatch". What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What type is element?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Isn't it a Cell if I do For Each loop on Cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure that you declare `element` as a range. Second, remove the `.cells` from your loop. This then effectively says in your loop statement `For each cell in the range` like so:

```
Sub SomeProc()

Dim element As Range
Dim MaxRows As Long

With Worksheets("parsed")
    MaxRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each element In Worksheets("parsed").Range("X1:X" & MaxRows)
    If IsNumeric(element.Value) Then
        element.Value = element.Value / 60
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I've made the assumption that `MaxRows` is intended as the last row in column `X` of the worksheet.

Comment: I still have type mismatch. What could be the cause?

Comment: Which line is the data mismatch occurring?

Comment: On the element.Value = element.Value / 60

Comment: That'll mean that one of the cells doesn't contain an number. I've updated the answer to check first that the value of the cell is a number using the function `IsNumeric`

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim CurRow As Long
For CurRow = 1 to MaxRows
    element = Worksheets("parsed").Range("X" & CurRow).Value / 60
    'Do something with element for example Range(Destination).Value = element
Next CurRow
```